# Java-Hashset-checking whether a given string is substring of some element

Tags: java, string, substring, complexity-theory, hashset

I am storing few elements in hashset in Java, suppose "hello world" ,"small elephant" , "hellostack", "others".  Now, I have string suppose "hello", which I want to check whether it is substring of any element in the given hashset. Here, it is a substring of "helloworld" and  "hellostack".

**Advantage**: I already know that, there are no string like "stackhello" or  "world hello". I mean, whatever string I want to compare, I already know that **it is always in prefix**, and not in between or in suffix of the elements in the hashset.

**Note:** I am not asking to traverse the whole hashset to check it!!!!
I need an efficient way, like I could check that in O(n) time

If it is not possible please suggest an efficient way(probably in O(n) complexity), without using hashset.

Comment: You want to check every element without checking every element?

Comment: Which would you prefer, to check every element, or to use a different data structure? The different data structure could be instead of, or in addition to, the HashSet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you correctly. It seems like you are trying to search on the words you have for the ones that have a substring.

I believe what you are looking for is a suffix tree. With it you can search matching words with a substring of any words in the set.

The description of the algorithm is here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_suffix_tree

And a implementation that seems good in Java: https://github.com/abahgat/suffixtree

I hope it pushes you in the right direction.

Comment: That's actually the *opposite* of what the OP wants. A regular `trie` would be the way to go.

Answer (score -2):

> I am not asking to traverse the whole hashset to check it!!!!

Then you're asking the impossible. Using `HashSet` you need to iterate through the set and do a comparison against each `String`.

If your primary use case is seeing if a supplied prefix matches a word(s) in the data structure, a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is actually what you want, with a method providing that functionality added to the implementation (Note that Java does not include a Trie implementation in the JDK, but it's fairly trivial to implement and/or you can find implementations on the 'net).

Determining if there's an existing word that the supplied prefix matches is a linear (`O(n)`) function in both.

Using a `HashSet` you have an outer loop (the iteration through the `HashSet`) and an independent inner loop (the `String` comparison). This is `O(N*M)` which is reduced to `O(n)`.

With a Trie it's still linear but the size of `n` is smaller as it's a single traversal of the structure based on the size of the input (prefix) `String`.

The difference is insert performance for the words themselves; with a `Trie` it's O(n) vs. O(1) with the `HashSet`